# Python:SMTP init method hangs when used in try:except block

Tags: python, sockets, exception, smtplib, getaddrinfo

I am trying to send some backtraces via email for which i am using the python `SMTP` lib.

My code looks like this

```
def send_email_thread(from_addr, to_addr, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.googlemail.com", 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(SENDMAIL_SMTP_USER, SENDMAIL_SMTP_PASSWD)
    server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, message)
    server.quit()
```

The actual code where i am trying to get the traceback

```
try:
    /*Something here that gives exception*/
except Exception:
    send_email_thread(from_addr,to_addr, str(traceback.format_exc()))
```

Now the problem is that the line

```
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.googlemail.com", 587)
```

hangs and does not return. On digging the issue a little i found that `__init__` for `SMTP` class calls `connect()` which in turn calls socket function `createconnection` which uses linux's `getaddrinfo()`

Call path:

```
mycode-->smtplib.SMTP---> __init__--->connect---->createconnection()--->getaddrinfo()
```

The `getaddrinfo()` call never returns. This is the hang point. What could be the problem? Also, I don't receive any traceback  or exception from `SMTP` lib. Is that because I am already catching an exception?

This only happens when i call the `send_mail_thread()` function inside the `except` block. From above:

```
except Exception:
    send_email_thread(from_addr,to_addr, str(traceback.format_exc()))
```

I tried by placing it outside and it worked! Which signals that the catching the exception and then running this might have caused the issue? Any pointers? I am using python 2.7 on Linux

[edit]

After some of the comments below i wanted to add the following update. The code runs inside a process created from another main process(using `multiprocessing` module). The `send_email_function` is then called inside a thread of this child process.

I created a simpler program to test this in which everything was being done in one process. And it worked out. Which means that there is some problem(deadlock) with how `getaddrinfo()` behaves when there is an exception in some child process or how well the `multiprocessing` modules handles POSIX calls

Comment: Did you try to write a minimal version that does not use threads? It may be some kind of deadlock due to threads.

Comment: Actually there is little more to it, This code executes in a child process which is created by some init code. So basically we have this running inside a thread of a child process. I will try to write a simple version

Comment: Be aware that mixing processes and threads you can obtain strange behaviours(e.g. using `logging` will probably deadlock your program).
Without a minimal example is probably really hard to understand where the real problem is.
By they way try to catch a less general exception class. You probably just care for `OSError` or `IOError` and for an exception in general, so maybe there is something else that is going wrong but it is shadowed by you `try` block.

Comment: Try to read [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2002-September/028555.html) it seems to be related.

Comment: I am not mixing threads and processes inside one process. What i meant by my comment was that the actual code runs inside a child process. However a launch a thread inside this child process that just to send out the email without getting blocked. I dont think that qualifies under "mixing processes and threads"

Comment: @Bakuriu i just tried with a simple program and it worked. Now this becomes even more difficult to debug and diagnose in this case

Comment: Having same issue as you. Any luck?